# Model in Partial View Did Not Return Any Data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I'm not quite sure what I missed here. I have call a Chat Controller in `_Layout` like below :

```
<div id="ChatContainer" class="chat-popup">
    @Html.Action("Index", "Chats")
</div>
```

The controller return partial view with a model like below :

```
public class ChatsController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var chats = db.Set<Chat>().ToList();
        return PartialView("_Index", chats);
    }
}
```

Then the partial view rendered :

```
@model IEnumerable<ERP.Models.Chat>

@{
    Layout = null;
}

@{
    foreach (var chat in Model)
    {
        @Html.Raw(chat.Message);
    }
}
```

This is not return any error and did not return any data. I try to trace with SQL Profiler, this is not even fire the table chat.

Comment: If  the table is not fired it's EF problem not the mvc one!

Comment: You need to use `Html.RenderAction`

Comment: Did you debug the code? Code of Index action is executed or not?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Yes, it is executed. I try to add some plain text in `_Index` and it showed

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I try with `@{Html.RenderAction("Index", "Chats")}` also didn't work

Comment: @JunRikson How are you calling the `Index` method?

Comment: @TanvirArjel Via Html.Action in _Layout

Comment: Its seems something mismatches..Can you give me remote access to the whole thing?

Comment: @JunRikson Do your controller have any cachable attribute? I got this kind of issue once.

Comment: @TanvirArjel : I tried created dummy project with this issolation issue, and this is working correctly. I suspect something happens from last time I updated the nuget package (SignalR). I am trying to download the project from git again, and re-download the package again. Because reverting from last commit doesn't work too. I think this is not code problem. I am still figuring out.

Comment: @t-prisar : I'm not quite sure what cachable atribute is. But I do session login expired for 30 minutes if not doing anything. I tried deploy in new server, move it to other pc, the one I didn't try yet is compiling in another pc. I will update again if build in other pc also did not work. From my dummy project, it seems not code problem, this code working good in test project.

Answer (score 1):

Your Entity Framework code looks OK. I am just wondering whether the connecting string passed to the ApplicationDbContext is the same database which you are profiling and have the data in. It's sometimes easy to miss this out since Entity Framework with default policy will automatically create a database if it doesn't exist.

[Updated]

Your partial view code is bit incorrect. The following is the write one:

```
@model IEnumerable<ERP.Models.Chat>

@{
    Layout = null;
}

@{
    foreach (var chat in Model)
    {
       @Html.Raw(chat.Message) // Put the @ symbol before Html
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is in same database. And the table already exist in database. I tried to delete the database and do `update-database` and the table created succesfully. I will try create new project for isolating the issue. Thank you.

Comment: OK, check the updated answer. This might be the root cause. There is nothing wrong with your EF code.

Comment: I give you +1 for that catch, I'm so sorry I missed that, I just created it for example. But in real code, it is have `@`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
public class ChatsController : Controller
{
  public ActionResult Index()
    {
          using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
          {
            var chats = db.Set<Chat>().ToList();
            return PartialView("_Index", chats);
          }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm so sorry all. Look like this is not coding problem.

I don't know what caused by this. I try to load all package in another PC and compile it and this is working good.

I'm sorry I can't really give an answer here, but last time I remember is updating `SignalR` and changing the id from `Guid` to `Int`.